# Separate a linked list and calculate each item in the list

Tags: python

I am trying to take this nested list:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I want to try and get the results, run this calculation:

```
fe = first element * 12
se = fe * second element
te = se * third element
```

I want to do this every single time where each list values are inputted and outputted separately.

Comment: By *first element*, do you mean the list? Please elaborate more on the question

Comment: First element in the first list, then the second element in the first list, then the third element in the first list. After first element in the second list, second element in the second list.....

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for triad in my_list:

    fe = triad[0] * 12
    se = fe * triad[1]
    te = se * triad[2]


    print(fe, se, te)
```

PS dont name your list variables "list" - its a built in name.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name your variables like builtin functions, modules or classes - list is a builtin class. Anyway, `list` is not really descriptive.

```py
input_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for first, second, third in input_list:
    fe = first * 12
    se = fe * second
    te = se * third
    print(fe, se, te)
```